# Remove single file in PHP

Tags: php

I need to delete a file. With what I have so far I end up deleting all files.

How would I delete a single file?

```
<?php
function delete($descarga){
    $link = $descarga;
    unlink($link);
}

$path="ficheros/"; 
$directorio=dir($path);
while ($archivo = $directorio->read())
{
    if($archivo === '.' || $archivo === '..') {continue;}
    $descarga = $path."".$archivo;
    echo "<a href=".$descarga.">".$archivo."</a>"."<a title='Delete' href='#' onclick=".delete($descarga)."><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>"."<br>";
}   

$directorio->close();
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all respective to the code you have posted. Please, make it more clear.

Comment: I want to delete a file from an icon with the method UNLINK @MuntashirAkon

Comment: I think the glyphicon has nothing to do with your problem, so I would edit that from the question description. Also, from what I understand, WHen you try to delete a file, all files get deleted instead, is that right?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Might you help me? @cavpollo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not clear at first, but I see whats wrong with the code you provided.

First you grab all the files from the directory.
Then you attempt to create delete links to the files that aren't folders.
But here is the thing, every time you create a link, you are calling `delete()` in your code. So every time this code is executed, all files are deleted right away even though links are displayed on the page. Just try to load the page, don't click anything, and you will see.

So the problem here is that you are confusing/mixing server-side-code with client-side-code. Once the page is rendered, you cant have access to the PHP code you wrote. So this means you cant have access to your `delete` function from the onclick Javascript event, as PHP is server-side-code and Javascript is client-side-code.

What you need are 2 PHP files. One that displays the files and its delete buttons, like this:

```
/display_files.php
<?php
   $path="ficheros/"; 
   $directorio=dir($path);
   while ($archivo = $directorio->read())
   {
      if($archivo === '.' || $archivo === '..') {continue;}
      $descarga = $path."".$archivo;
      echo "<a href=\"".$descarga."\">".$archivo."</a>"."<a title=\"Delete\" href=\"/path/to/delete/file.php?borrar_archivo=".$descarga."\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span></a><br>";
   }  

   $directorio->close();
?>
```

And another one that receives the file to be deleted as a parameter, like this (haven't tested it, but should be close to what you need):

```
/path/to/delete/file.php
<?php
   $link = $_GET["borrar_archivo"];
   unlink($link);
?>
```

Of course, this approach isn't secure by any means because you are letting anybody call the URL to delete anything they like, but it serves the purpose you are looking for.

Let me know if something isn't clear enough.